# how to get menu label in monkeyrunner.?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, gui-testing, ui-testing

I want to get the menu list items from an android phone. Are there any methods in *monkeyrunner* to fetch this?

Answer (score 2):

From the monkeyrunner description:

> Functional testing: monkeyrunner can run an automated start-to-finish
>   test of an Android application. You provide input values with
>   keystrokes or touch events, and view the results as screenshots.
>   Regression testing - monkeyrunner can test application stability by
>   running an application and comparing its output screenshots to a set
>   of screenshots that are known to be correct.

So i think, you can't fetch anything, but you can specify a "correct" screenshot and compare it automatically with an actual screenshot to make functional tests.

**EDIT:** However, you can let monkeyrunner "press" the menu-button via `device.press(KEYCODE_MENU, DOWN_AND_UP)`, take a screenshot and compare it to another one.

Comment: hi,we can fetch info like device.getProperty('am.current.action'),device.getProperty('display.width')..is there anything like display.label or something..

Comment: @user964772 No. There is a complete table of what you can get with device.getProperty() here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#table1 These are more global properties like system clock, display size, not really application specific.

Comment: hi wonne,thanks for the reply.the list doesnt contains fetching a menu label.what i want to do is make a script which scans for wifi network and connect to one specified network.So i want to read all scanned wifi n/ws and match to my required network ssid.taking screen shot and comparing is not practical because the scanned network lists may differ according to the signal strength.